# Easy way to change theme and storage it - Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, storage

I have this element. I want to change its **color** and its **font size** when user click button

```
<h1> Hello Stackoverflow </h1>
<button (click)="changeTheme()">Change Theme</button>
```

what is good way to change theme and storage it ( to stay changes when user open app again ) with Ionic app

> knowing that I have many pages and I want to change its font size and its color

Comment: What research have you done. A single web search showed refs to this problem in forums and even [so].

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities: localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API, sessionStorage, cookies etc.

With LocalStorage simply set the item's key you want with the value you want:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('themeColor', '#your color value or theme name');
```

And read it as such:

```
const storedColor = window.localStorage.getItem('themeColor');
```

And remove it like this:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('themeColor')
```

For more elaborate stuffs you can use [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) which is great.

Comment: Hi **t3_rry**  on Ionic we use typescript not javascript. I can not use javascript with Ionic App 

Comment: @AmjedOmar Sorry I didn't see that. I wish you luck then :D

Comment: is that even possible to use sessionStorage in Ionic? I thought there is Storage type which acts like localStorage but I could not find anything similar for sessionStorage